# System.Windows.Forms.AxHost InvalidActiveXStateException vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb6, vb6-migration

When i was converting VB to VB.NET, i found the error `InvalidActiveXStateException`.
My program ahs a main form and many sub forms, and while I am checking the sub forms, one of them has this error and can not open that form, but the other forms can be opened correctly.
The code is the same. Why i can not open that form?

I had been researched from internet and most of people said that :

```
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.ax)).BeginInit();

this.Controls.Add(ax);

((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.ax)).EndInit();
```

but it seem C# not VB.NET and i dont know when can i found the name of ax in my program.
here is part of my program code.

```
Public Sub mnu_dceedc_enq_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs        As System.EventArgs) Handles mnu_dceedc_enq.Click
    If bolCheckSecurity("dcs_eedc_enq") Then
        Unload_frm()
        DCformfun = mnu_dceedc_enq.Name
        frmDCEEDC.Show()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chkfiltercase_CheckStateChanged(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles chkfiltercase.CheckStateChanged
    '20090401
    'fgdetail_Click

    Call ShowFolderDetail(fgdetail.get_TextMatrix(fgdetail.Row, 1), fgdetail.get_TextMatrix(fgdetail.Row, 2), CShort(txtbatchno.Text))
End Sub
```

When I open a sub form, it will start from `nu_dceedc_enq_Click` and then go to `chkfiltercase_CheckStateChanged` but when ran into `Call ShowFolderDetail`, it auto returns back to `form.show()` and the exception occurs.

Why does this error occur and how can I solve it?

**Update after testing:**

I tried commenting all the Sub `chkfiltercase_CheckStateChanged` and the form occur success and I am try to test whether it will occur others or not.

Comment: sure! but when the answers occurred first =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of what the standard conversion/usage of active x controls does is create a state for the control.  This state is not always set/created correctly and will sometimes get changed when you run the application in the debugger.  When the state is invalid, this exception is thrown.  I generally try to replace the active x control with a .net control (either one that already exists or creating an equivalent).

Supposedly some of the commercal alternatives to the standard tool will avoid this problem.

Comment: Thank you,  comment Handles chkfiltercase.CheckStateChanged can be solved, i guess the problem of sequence

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I tried the proposed solutions of calling CreateControl without any success.

It turned out that the interops were generated targeting the .net 2.0 framework and the problem occurred when being called from 4.0 code.  The solution was to generate interops using [.NET Framework Tools 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9kh6s92%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).